# How to accept dynamic inputs in qt

Tags: qt, input

Hi in Linux if we give command **SU** it asks for password and if we enter right password it **login's to super user**,in the similar fashion how can i do this through **Qt application**

What classes to be used,is it possible to do so ..?

Comment: I suggest to you that you use a dialog window to obtain the password. Here is an example: https://wiki.qt.io/User_Login_Dialog

Answer (score 1):

You can the [QLineEdit class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html) then connect the signal [returnPressed](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#returnPressed) with a method which will save the first string, change the echo mode with [setEchoMode()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#echoMode-prop) and set it to QLineEdit::Password and then when the user erite the second time he will see what he write like ***** and when he will press enter you can get the password in the same method you connected with the returnPressed signal.

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_returnPressed()
{
  if (ui->lineEdit->echoMode() == QLineEdit::Password) {
    _pwd = ui->lineEdit->text();
    ui->lineEdit->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Normal);
    // your job after getting the password here
  }
  else {
    _loggin = ui->lineEdit->text();
    ui->lineEdit->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi can i login into root using any gui application say so Qt,
If i run **system(su)** in my Qt application and if i enter my root password through **ui** can i  login...?

If possible where and how should i send the password..?

Comment: there is no way with su/sudo/etc to send the password in the command for security reasons. so you can't do things like sudo -u <username> -p <password>. however you can run your qt application as root. the nearest way to do that is to use the -S of sudo and change the TTY of the standart input with pipe2.